# Find the number of occurrences in an array using reduce in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I was trying to find a solution to find out the number of occurrences of a number in an array and came across the below solution:

```
const occurrences = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4].reduce(function (acc, curr) {
  return acc[curr] ? ++acc[curr] : acc[curr] = 1, acc
}, {});

console.log(occurrences)
```

The code above works as expected. But I am not able to understand properly how it works. Can someone please simplify and explain the reduce method above? Thanks in advance.

Comment: think it as a for loop where you initialize an object `obj` `{}` outside the loop. in the loop you check if `obj[num]` exists if not initialize to 1 otherwise increment 1

Comment: it would easier if you ask about the specific parts that you don't understand.

Comment: So far, everyone has been describing the left side of the [ternary operator (`?`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) as testing for whether the key/value/etc. **exists**, but that's not correct: it evaluates the expression as [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)/[falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) (and `0` is included as falsy). To check whether the key **exists**, you'd need to use `curr in acc ? ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method in JavaScript is used to iterate over an array and based on some logic accumulate a single value from it.

Let's break down the code:

```
const occurrences = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4].reduce(function (acc, curr) {
    return acc[curr] ? ++acc[curr] : acc[curr] = 1, acc
}, {});
```

The [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method takes two arguments:

A *function* that is executed on each element of the *array*. This *function* takes two parameters: the *accumulator* (`acc`) and the current value being processed (`curr`). The *accumulator* is the value that is returned and accumulated on each iteration of the *function*.

An optional initial value for the *accumulator*. In this case, the initial value is an empty object `{}`.

let's find out the *function* being passed as the first argument to [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
function (acc, curr) {
  return acc[curr] ? ++acc[curr] : acc[curr] = 1, acc
}
```

On each iteration, this function checks if the current value (`curr`) already exists as a key in the accumulator (`acc`). If it does, it increments the *value* of that *key*. If not, it adds the *key* to the accumulator with a *value* of 1.

Breaking down the logic:

```
return acc[curr] ? ++acc[curr] : acc[curr] = 1, acc
```

- `acc[curr] ?`:This checks if the current *value* (`curr`) exists as a *key* in the accumulator (`acc`).
- `++acc[curr]`: If the key exists, it increments the value associated with that *key*.
- `: acc[curr] = 1`: If the *key* does not exist, it adds the *key* to the accumulator with a value of 1.
- `, acc`: Finally, the updated accumulator is returned.

In each iteration, the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method is either incrementing the count for an existing number or initializing a count of 1 for a new number in the `acc` object.

After all the iterations are complete, the final value of the accumulator object is assigned to the occurrences variable and printed to the console:

```
console.log(occurrences) // {2: 5, 4: 1, 5: 3, 9: 1}
```

This shows that there are 5 occurrences of the number 2, 3 occurrences of the number 5, 1 occurrence of the number 4, and 1 occurrence of the number 9 in the original array.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the tricky part is just:

```
return acc[curr] ? ++acc[curr] : acc[curr] = 1, acc
```

Note that this is just:

```
return (some_expression_with_side_effects), acc
```

...which returns `acc`.  Take a look at the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_operator) in JavaScript for details. In short, the expression `a, b` equals `b`.  Using this as a return value for reduce just ensures that the the accumulator is always the same object `acc`.  But we add properties to that object as we reduce.

As we reduce items in the array, the side-effect expression does the following:

- if there is a count for the current item, then increment it
- if there is not a count yet, then add it and initialize it to 1.

Note that we don't actually use the return value of `++acc[curr]`, we just rely on the side-effect that it actually increments the values stored at `acc[curr]`.  And similarly, we don't return the value of the expression `acc[curr] = 1`, but rather, we rely on the side-effect that it actually sets `acc[curr]` to an initial value of `1`.